# Are geolocation apps based on latitude and longitude data?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geo

Are most web and smartphone applications that show you how far other users are from you essentially based on a user's latitude and longitude?  That is, do these apps basically derive a user's latitude and longitude from their country and postal code and then use an algorithm to create a sorted list of all users who are near them, closest first?  I believe the answer is "yes" but I want to make sure before I build this feature into my Django application.

For those countries that don't use postal codes, I would imagine the latitude and longitude are derived from the city/region/country tuple they reside in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they map IP to lat/long, and lat/long to city, and city to country, unless they have access to a GPS device/sensor for the exact position (+/- 1m).

The thing is, if you have an ip, you can convert that into a number (biginteger)

```
74.88.21.55  ==> (a.b.c.d) ==> d * 255^0 + c * 255^1 + b * 255^2 +a * 255^3 = x
```

then you can query a database.
All you need is a lookup-table:

T_Lookup

```
IP_Range_Start   IP_Range_End    Latitute     Longitue
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT Latitude, Longitude FROM T_Lookup
WHERE x BETWEEN IP_Range_Start AND IP_Range_End
```

Then you can calculate the distance between the two points using the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

You can grab C code here:
http://aimbots.net/tutorials/7680-getting-country-ip-address.html

And an IP to country csv you find here:
http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/6

Answer (score 0):

Apps that display the locations of users relative to other users generally gather their data from either GPS data or IP address location data.

[This Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation) provides a nice explanation of geolocation.

Answer (score 0):

They use the Galactic Coordinate system, which does in fact use longitude, l, and latitude, b.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system

Comment: Haha, good one. BTW, GPS uses WGS84 (World Geodetic System‎ 1984).

Comment: Ya, I had the same laugh - his answer is for objects in outer space.